# Dropdown JQuery not working without Homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

This code working on home page but can't working on any other page I can't understand what is the problem in it.

In codeigniter config file 'csrf_protection' is also FALSE.

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#services").hover(
    function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");$(this).toggleClass('open');},
    function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).not('.in .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp("fast");$(this).toggleClass('open');}
    );
});
```

HTML

```
<li id="services" class="dropdown" data-wow-delay="0.2s"><a <?= active('services') ?> data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Services</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/dry-cleaning') ?>">Dry Cleaning</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/fluff-fold') ?>">Fluff & Fold</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/wedding-gowns') ?>">Wedding Gowns</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/drapery') ?>">Drapery</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/table-bed-linens') ?>">Table & Bed Linens</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/alterations') ?>">Alterations</a></li>
     <li><a href="<?= base_url('services/purse-rug-leather-cleaning') ?>">Purse | Rug | Leather Cleaning</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript error console?

Comment: Yes.!! It show TypeError: c is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved this query..!! there is conflict with `slider.js` another pages don't have slider just home page have slider so, another pages don't need `slider.js`.

I just remove `slider.js` from all other pages. that's solve.

Answer (score 1):

One probable explanation can be that you have included the jquery library on your homepage but not on the other pages. Try

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    alert("Alerted Text");
});
```

on any of the pages other than the homepage and see if jQuery is working

Comment: I am working with codeigniter and i used master page for that so, i have added javascript and dropdown-menu in master page i already tried alert it's show on homepage. other pages show TypeError: c is undefined. in Consol JS

Answer (score 1):

Just check for id services on other pages if its there then it should work if not then you can change $("#services") to $(".someclass") here someclass is any common class name